# I am having an error on accessing a file from another directory with Python

Tags: python

This is my Python code:

```py
from plugin import Plugin

import logging

import yaml

log = logging.getLogger('discord')

def get_bot_prefix():
    with open('HarTex/hartexConfig.yaml', 'r') as prefixReader:
        prefixValue = yaml.safe_load(prefixReader)

        prefixString = prefixValue['settings']['prefix']

    return prefixString


prefix = get_bot_prefix()
```

However I got an error with the file accessing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/85251/Documents/Discord Bots/Python/HarTex/bot.py", line 20, in <module>
    from plugins.help import Help
  File "C:\Users\85251\Documents\Discord Bots\Python\HarTex\plugins\help.py", line 30, in <module>
    prefix = get_bot_prefix()
  File "C:\Users\85251\Documents\Discord Bots\Python\HarTex\plugins\help.py", line 22, in get_bot_prefix
    with open('HarTex/hartexConfig.yaml', 'r') as prefixReader:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'HarTex/hartexConfig.yaml'
```

How can I fix it? Or am I completely wrong with the directory?

Comment: is your `hartexConfig.yaml` in the same directory as the `bot.py`?

Comment: Yes, it is... I wonder if this question is related to the solution?

Comment: so if you run it from the same directory, Try to use `with open('hartexConfig.yaml', 'r') as prefixReader:`

Comment: it seems you run code in different folder then you think. Use `print( os.getcwd() )` to see it. You can also check files in current folder `print( os.listdir() )`

Answer (score 0):

The script should work if you are calling it from the parent directory of HarTex, maybe you are running it from a different working directory?

You could also try to open the file using the full path, as this is probably easy to check.

Answer (score 0):

Error is very clear.You should use absolute path instead of relative path.

**For an example** home/Prakash/Desktop/test12/test.yaml

Your code definitely work,Once you will change path like this.